# Devise confirm account and set password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my app I am using Devise and Active Admin. Users are created in admin area without password, then they receive a mail with a link to a confirmation page where they can enter the password for the new account.

This is confirmation controller:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  def show
    @original_token = params[:confirmation_token]
    digested_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :confirmation_token,params[:confirmation_token])
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(digested_token) if params[:confirmation_token].present?
    super if resource.nil? or resource.confirmed?
    render :layout => "internal"
    end


  def confirm
    digested_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :confirmation_token, params[resource_name][:confirmation_token])
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(digested_token) if params[resource_name][:confirmation_token].present?
    if resource.update_attributes(params[resource_name].except(:confirmation_token).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)) && resource.password_match?
      self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[resource_name][:confirmation_token])
      set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
  sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)

    else
      @original_token =  params[resource_name][:confirmation_token]
      render :action => "show", :layout => "internal"
    end    
    
  end
  
end
```

Relevant routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd', :controllers => {:confirmations => 'confirmations'}

  devise_scope :user do
    patch "/confirm" => "confirmations#confirm"
  end
```

When the users clicks on the activation link in the background it sets the account as confirmed in the database, but instead of being redirected to confirmations/show to set the password, I get on this line render :layout => "internal"

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
> Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
> once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
> execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
> redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
> return".

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please try `render :layout => "internal" and return`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ConfirmationsController`:

```rb
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  def show
    @original_token = params[:confirmation_token]
    digested_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :confirmation_token,params[:confirmation_token])
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(digested_token) if params[:confirmation_token].present?
    # here you call super if resource is nil or confirmed
    # super calls the show action of Devise::ConfirmationController
    # it results with the first render (but doesn't call any return)
    super if resource.nil? or resource.confirmed?
    # after super is finished you continue and render layout internal
    # (again, since it has happened in the parent controller already)
    render :layout => "internal"
  end
...
```

you can check what exactly is being done in `Devise::ConfirmationsController` on their github page: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb

if you want to render render the confirmations/show page then just remove the

```rb
render layout: 'internal'
```

line.

Comment: Yes I ended up removing that line and add layout "internal" on top of controller as there are only 2 actions both using internal template